# cannot import name 'AuthorityMatchInfo' from 'pyproj._crs'

Tags: import, metpy

I am trying to use the calc module in metpy. I have installed it both via pip and 'conda forge' option. When i run my script in spyder, i get the following error

ImportError: cannot import name 'AuthorityMatchInfo' from 'pyproj._crs' eg Example file path : (~anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/_crs.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full error traceback rather than the last error message? That's going to be important for debugging. Also, what versions of pyproj did you get with pip and conda-forge?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue two times and solved it by following advice I found on [github](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1709#issuecomment-782938084).

Basically one needs to uninstall pyproj and reinstall.